# Poptop configured for freeradius but still authenticates through chap

Tags: vpn, pptp, freeradius, freeradius2

I'm running Centos 6 64 bit with Poptop and radiusclient. When I connect to my poptop server this error comes up in the error log:

```
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pptpd[13225]: CTRL: Client **** control connection started
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pptpd[13225]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Warning: can't open options file /root/.ppprc: Permission denied
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Plugin radattr.so loaded.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: RADATTR plugin initialized.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pptpd[13225]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: rc_get_ipaddr: couldn't resolve hostname: alpha
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: rc_own_ipaddress: couldn't get own IP address
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Peer sdf failed CHAP authentication
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Connection terminated.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: Exit.
Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pptpd[13225]: CTRL: Client **** control connection finished
```

It says failed CHAP authentication but it's configured for freeradius? If I check my freeradius in debug mode it doesn't say anything about incoming queries.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: rc_get_ipaddr: couldn't resolve hostname: alpha
> Feb 21 14:40:42 alpha pppd[13226]: rc_own_ipaddress: couldn't get own IP address
> ```

Had That Problem on a IPv6 only Machine, try Executing:

```
#ping alpha
```

If it fails, verify that there is an IPv4 match for alpha in /etc/hosts, like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost alpha
```